# Entity frame work Remove, RemoveRange and EntityState Deleted

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

What is the difference between these three lines

```
var courses = _context.Courses
                                      .Include("AssignedCustomers")
                                      .Include("PricingSchedule")
                                      .Include("Licenses")
                                      .Include("GroupCourses")
                                      .Include("GroupLicenses")
                                      .Where(e => courseIds.Contains(e.Id)).ToList();

 courses.ForEach(currentCourse =>
                        {
```

**First**

```
_context.CustomerCourses.RemoveRange(currentCourse.AssignedCustomers);
```

**Second**

```
 currentCourse.AssignedCustomers.ToList().ForEach(ac =>
                        {
                            _context.Entry(ac).State = EntityState.Deleted;
                        });
```

**Third**

```
currentCourse.AssignedCustomers.ToList().ForEach(ac =>
                        {
                            currentCourse.AssignedCustomers.Remove(ac);

                        });
        }
```

When to use what and in which scenario? I always stuck to identify which one should be used. I try every approach whichever works for me I keep it. But honestly I don't understand the concept here

Answer (score 1):

The Remove Range() method is used to remove a collection or a list within entity framework. This is a better alternative to using a loop to iterate over the collection and set the entity state of the object to Deleted.

```
IList<Book> booksToRemove = new List<Book>() {
                                new Book() { BookId = 1, BookName = "Rich Dad Poor Dad" };
                                new Book() { BookId = 2, BookName = "The Great Gatsby" };
                                new Book() { BookId = 3, BooktName = "The Kite Runner" };
                            };
using (var context = new LibraryDBEntities()) {
context.Books.RemoveRange(booksToRemove);
context.SaveChanges(); }
```

In the above example, RemoveRange(booksToRemove) sets the state of all the entities of the list "booksToRemove" as deleted and performs a DELETE command for all the entities on context.SaveChanges().

RemoveRange is an alternative method that you can use instead of the second and third option posted above. It is recommended to use RemoveRange and AddRange for deleting and inserting a large number of records using entity framework.

Comment: In EF6, the xxxRange methods may perform much better than the individual methods because the change tracker only performs `DetectChanges` once per method vs.n `times` for each individual method. In EF-core, this benefit is gone. There's now one notification of the change tracker for each entity, I guess because of more complex cascading state changes. The remaining advantage is shorter code.

Comment: If i use my third approach then I am unable to savechnages it gives me error while RemoveRange works fine. Why is that?

Comment: @HaseebKhan Probably because that's not the same as the former two methods. The third method only cuts a relationship. But you should ask a new questions giving appropriate details it you need more help.